# Named Pipes error in SQL Server 2008 and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, named-pipes

I just want to connect to the local server manually. I right clicked on the "Data Connections" button in "Server Explorer", and then selected "Create New SQL Server Database". But Named Pipes provided error occured. I tried every suggested solution on the internet. Changed SQL Server Network Configuration, opened the port 1433 as told me. Restarted computer, reinstalled everything, but no, it just doesn't work.
Here you can see possible errors;

[MSDN Named Pipes Provider](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/16/named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error-xxx.aspx)

In my situation xxx=2. I thought i don't need connection string because i'm connecting manually without code or something. And also when i open a DB project or Server Project in visual studio i still can't make them work. Are there any suggestions? And i know there are other questions similar but they don't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i'm connecting manually without code or something

I assume this means you're trying to connect through Management Studio?

- Why not use the server name 'localhost\myInstance' and see if you can connect that way?
- Have you checked the connection string when you connect via Management Studio? If you're connecting to a default instance, make sure you're not including `\MSSQLSERVER` on the end of the server name. If you named your instance when installing make sure you're using that.
- Have you checked that Named Pipes is enabled for this instance in Config Manager -> Network Configuration?
- Have you checked the SQL Server service is running?

Comment: I checked last two of your suggestions and they are ok. Tried first one now but it didn't help. I don't have any oen project right now. But i guess i should still be able to connect via visual studio. But i'm newbie so i am not sure if i should enter connection string somewhere.

Comment: @AhmetGunes Which menu option are you choosing in VS? Where connecting to a server is necessary it should prompt you with the same logon box as you would get as if you opened SQL Server Management Studio from your program files (presuming you chose to install the management component at install time).

What are you entering into the server name box on that logon screen?

Comment: @AhmetGunes It might also be worth starting the SQL Browser service - shouldn't be so much of an issue as it's a local SQL Server instance, but you never know!

Comment: I was entering the suggested one. "AH-PC" ,i  changed it to AH-PC\MSSQLSERVER as you said and it didn't work. But then i changed it to AH-PC\SQLEXPRESS (i was just guessing) and it worked. I don't know thanks to you i guess :D

Comment: Yes i enabled it too randomly. I was really desperate so i decided to try everything and i think that solved the problem.

Comment: No I said make sure it _doesn't_ have MSSQLSERVER in it if it's a default instance! So you'd installed it as a named instance, the instance name is `SQLEXPRESS`, but you were trying to connect as if you had installed a default instance.